# Textview in tableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, textview

Each tableviewcell holds a textView.

When tap on the attributedText(contains URL for visiting in SFSafariViewController) in textview very fast, "tableView didSelectRowAt" get called then textView delegate "shouldInteractWith URL" called too. Pushed a blank white SFSafariView and no way to get back.

If tap on attributedText and hold until the attributedText behaves like "touched", it works fine.

So, my problem is how can i prevent textviewdelegate get called when user tap the textview very fast and make sure only the tableviewdelegate responds that action?
Thanks!

Comment: you can set the isUserInteractionEnabled field of the text view to false, then it will no longer respond to touch events

Comment: @BJHStudios but i need textview to respond user touches when tap on attributedText in textview.